# How to place close [x] in WPF popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have succeed creating a popup using this code in c# and wpf

```
<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="True">
<Label Name="myLabel" Content="This is a popup!" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </Popup>
```

I use the code below to hide it when one mouse-click outside it and it works right.

```
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
myPopup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Mouse;
myPopup.StaysOpen = false;
myPopup.Height = 500;
myPopup.Width = 500;
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

My problem is that I would like to add a close button(or something like [x]). It will hide when this is clicked, just like dialog in windows forms. Any ideas?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseDown="mouse_DownHandled">
        x
        </Label>
        <Label Name="myLabel" Content="This is a popup!" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

In the mouse_DownHandled event handler, you can add the code to close th popup

Comment: Great gprsant!And if I want to minimize to a status bar and maximize when I need it just like windows forms. Is it possible?Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In one of our apps we had a similar requirement and we solved it by binding `IsOpen` to a property of the view model. When you add a button use the `Click` event handler to set the property to false which will close the popup.

Comment: And if I want to minimize to a status bar and maximize when I need it just like windows forms. Is it possible?Any ideas?

Comment: @KiuFelix Then a `Popup` might not be the right kind of control to use. Best to post a separate question detailing what you want to achieve and see with what kind of ideas people come up with.