# WPF Popup like Windows Form

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to create a popup in wpf that behaves as windows form. I have manage to close the popup using [x] when it displays. I am stuck on how I can add functional minimize and maximize buttons feature.
here is how i achieved the first step: close button:
[How to place close [x] in WPF popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265812/how-to-place-close-x-in-wpf-popup)

```
<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseDown="mouse_DownHandled">
        x
        </Label>
        <Label Name="myLabel" Content="This is a popup!" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

the mouse_DownHandled event closes the popup by setting isOpen=false

Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you want. I think what you want is not a Popup Control but actually a WPF Window with a special style set in it. 
Use the WindowStyle property to achieve this.

Use

```
<Window Name="myPopup" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <StackPanel>
          <Label Name="myLabel" Content="This is a popup!" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you want to show this from the code, you can create create an instance of the view and call
window.Show()

Your window should look like this 
[image]

Comment: This is ok. I wonder why I couldn't figure this one out. I'm new in wpf and now learning a lot. Thanks once again.You saved my day

Comment: I you get a way of doing it using popup let me know. I like popup for its appearance. No borders and more so when customized one can use his buttons for close,min and maximize.